# What Center does an Administrator see?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to add a Custom Record Type and Form, I see how to create a Link to the form so it shows up on a menu. As an Administrator what Center do I see? System Administrator Center is the closest one I see but I never see the link on the menu.

I'm trying to create a custom page to set some parameters that the normal user should never have access to. The client should never see these parms either, what Role would be good to associate this custom form with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Administrator role uses the Classic Center.

Comment: I found a whole list of what roles use what center https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9798